# Отключить панель "Показать другие видео"

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Не могу отключить панель "Показать другие видео"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="ytplayer" class="player"></div>
            <script>
                    var tag = document.createElement('script');
                    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                    var ytplayer;
                    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
                        ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
                            videoId: '09VAnZKHxEA',
                            autoplay: 0,
                            playerVars: {
                                enablejsapi: 1,
                                rel: 0,
                                showinfo: 0
                            }
                        });
                    }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

rel=0 больше не скрывает связанные видео; теперь он будет показывать связанные видео, но, по крайней мере, они будут только с вашего канала. Изменения вступили в силу 25 сентября 2018 года (документация).

Answer (score 1):

так как это iframe, то

> Так как страница, которая загружается во фрейме, находится на другом домене, то у вас нет прав для доступа и редактирования этой страницы.
>   Что бы была возможность редактировать страница, которая загружает фрейм, и которая загружается во фрейме, должны быть на одном домене. Иначе нужно проксировать через свой сервер и домен